# No handler found for library with logging configured

Tags: python, logging

I configured logging, but I seem to missing a step. In this example, I'm using suds, but I have this issue with any library logging using this log method.

This works

```
host-03:~ # python2.7
Python 2.7.7 (default, Aug 27 2014, 16:51:46)
[GCC 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973]] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig()
>>> from suds.client import Client
>>> logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> client = Client('https://10.10.10.10:8443/path/to/wsdl?wsdl')
>>> user = 'User'
>>> password = 'pass'
>>> client.service.checkAuthentication(user, password)
DEBUG:suds.client:sending to (https://10.10.10.10:8443/path/to/wsdl)
message:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://DefaultNamespace" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns2:Body>
      <ns1:checkAuthentication>
         <username xsi:type="ns3:string">User</username>
         <password xsi:type="ns3:string">pass</password>
      </ns1:checkAuthentication>
   </ns2:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
DEBUG:suds.client:headers = {'SOAPAction': '""', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'}
DEBUG:suds.client:HTTP succeeded:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><ns1:checkAuthenticationResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://DefaultNamespace"><checkAuthenticationReturn xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</checkAuthenticationReturn></ns1:checkAuthenticationResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
True
>>>
```

But when I configure file and console logging like the following, any messages I send (by using the logger.debug and the like), work as expected, however, any log from a library always says "No handler found".

```
from datetime import datetime
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os

class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    """used for colored terminal logging"""
    BLACK, RED, GREEN, YELLOW, BLUE, MAGENTA, CYAN, WHITE = range(8)
    colors = dict(
        CRITICAL='\33[1;9%dm' % RED,
        ERROR='\33[9%dm' % RED,
        WARNING='\33[9%dm' % YELLOW,
        INFO='\33[1;9%dm' % GREEN,
        DEBUG='\33[9%dm' % BLUE,
        NOTSET='\33[%dm' % BLACK,  # reset
    )
    def __init__(self, fmt=None, datefmt=None, color=False):
        fmt = fmt if fmt else ('%(asctime)s %(module)-11s %(levelname)-9s '
                               '%(threadName)-10s %(message)s')
        logging.Formatter.__init__(self, fmt, datefmt)
        self.color = color
    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        create_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created)
        if datefmt:
            s = create_time.strftime(datefmt)
        else:
            t = create_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            s = "%s.%03d" % (t, record.msecs)
        return s
    def format(self, record):
        s = super(CustomFormatter, self).format(record)
        if self.color:
            s = self.colors[record.levelname] + s + self.colors['NOTSET']
        return s

# get logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# configure file handler
path_to_log = '/app/logs/app.log'
filehandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(path_to_log, backupCount=5)
filehandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
filehandler.setFormatter(CustomFormatter())
if os.path.isfile(path_to_log):
    filehandler.doRollover()

# configure stream handler
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
console.setFormatter(CustomFormatter(color=True))

# add handlers to logger
logger.addHandler(filehandler)
logger.addHandler(console)

# configure client
from suds.client import Client
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

client = Client('https://10.10.10.10:8443/path/to/wsdl?wsdl')
user = 'User'
password = 'pass'
client.service.checkAuthentication(user, password)


>>> client.service.checkAuthentication(user, password)
No handlers could be found for logger "suds.client"
True
>>>
```

logging works properly when I call them directly

```
>>> logger.debug('some test message')
2015-01-15 09:10:18.523 <stdin>     DEBUG     MainThread some test message
>>>
host-03:~ # cat /app/logs/app.log
2015-01-15 09:10:18.523 <stdin>     DEBUG     MainThread some test message
```

What am I missing from my logging configuration that is causing the libraries to not find my logging handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did manage to figure this out. What wasn't obvious... when you use any type of log config except basicConfig, file or dict config, existing loggers are disabled. If the library used

```
logger = logging.getLogger('your app or module')
```

Then it would work, but since they are all grabbing

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

then rolling your own logger leaves the lib without a configured handler. You have a couple of options.

Set your lib to a null handler (like in the above post, suds.client)

```
logging.getLogger('suds.client').addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

but that's not very useful if you want to see the messages

Or you can use file or dictConfig and specify `disable_existing_loggers=False`

I still wasn't happy with the results though. If you set the default log level to debug, your libs are going to pollute your output, but if you set the default to warning, that's not very useful for your own logging. You can set the libs independently though, but it can be a bit of a pain.

What I ended up doing, was to set the level to DEBUG, but I added a lib filter that sends any log record from a library to it's own file. Then after running an instance of my app, I looked through the logs to determine what I felt was useful, then lowered the level of those deemed unnecessary to WARN.

```
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport.http').setLevel(logging.WARN)
```

I ended up leaving the lib filter in, as it is useful for me to have a detailed trace of some of the libraries, but it's too much for my standard log. I also added some initialization to remove any previous logs with each instance of the app.

Following is a snippet similar to what I am using now.

```
"""some sample log"""
import os
import logging
import logging.config
import logging.handlers
from datetime import datetime

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    """used for colored terminal logging"""
    BLACK, RED, GREEN, YELLOW, BLUE, MAGENTA, CYAN, WHITE = range(8)
    colors = dict(
        CRITICAL='\33[1;9%dm' % RED,
        ERROR='\33[9%dm' % RED,
        WARNING='\33[9%dm' % YELLOW,
        INFO='\33[1;9%dm' % GREEN,
        DEBUG='\33[9%dm' % BLUE,
        NOTSET='\33[%dm' % BLACK,  # reset
    )

    def __init__(self, fmt=None, datefmt=None, color=False):
        fmt = fmt if fmt else ('%(asctime)s %(module)-11s %(levelname)-9s '
                               '%(threadName)-10s %(message)s')
        logging.Formatter.__init__(self, fmt, datefmt)
        self.color = color

    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        create_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created)
        if datefmt:
            s = create_time.strftime(datefmt)
        else:
            t = create_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            s = "%s.%03d" % (t, record.msecs)
        return s

    def format(self, record):
        s = super(CustomFormatter, self).format(record)
        if self.color:
            s = self.colors[record.levelname] + s + self.colors['NOTSET']
        return s


class LibFilter(logging.Filter):
    """custom filter to send suds logging to a separate file"""
    def filter(self, record):
        if [x for x in '__main__', __name__.split('.', 1)[0]
                if x in record.name]:
            return True
        else:
            create_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created)
            t = create_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            s = "%s.%03d" % (t, record.msecs)
            with open('logs/%s.log' % record.name, 'a') as f:
                f.write(s + '\n')
                f.write(record.getMessage() + '\n\n')
            return False


def setup_logging():
    """use dictConfig to setup logging"""
    log_file = 'logs/app.log'
    doRollover = os.path.isfile(log_file)
    logging.config.dictConfig(
        dict(
            version=1,
            disable_existing_loggers=False,
            filters=dict(libfilter={'()': LibFilter}),
            formatters=dict(
                colorformatter={'()': CustomFormatter, 'color': True},
                fileformatter={'()': CustomFormatter}),
            handlers=dict(
                console={
                    'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                    'filters': ['libfilter'],
                    'formatter': 'colorformatter',
                    'level': 'DEBUG'},
                filehandler={
                    'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                    'filename': log_file,
                    'backupCount': 3,
                    'filters': ['libfilter'],
                    'formatter': 'fileformatter',
                    'level': 'DEBUG'}),
            root=dict(level='INFO', handlers=['console', 'filehandler'])
        )
    )
    if doRollover:
        for handler in logging.getLogger('').handlers:
            if getattr(handler, 'doRollover', None):
                handler.doRollover()
```

And my test app

```
"""
    test logging configuration
"""
import logging

from mod import log
log.setup_logging()

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.debug('debug msg')
logger.info('info msg')
logger.warning('warning msg')
logger.error('error msg')
logger.exception('exception msg')
```

Now my console and file logs are as before, and for all my libs I get a separate file for each. I did not implement the rollover logic, but in my app, I am removing the prior library logs with each run of the app.